# Two Bijective Holomorphic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g : \mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{E}$ be bijective, holomorphic functions with $f(0) = g(0)$ and $f'(0) = g'(0)$. Also, $f'$ and $g'$ don't have zeros.
Prove $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{E}$. (Note: $\mathbb{E} := B_1(0)$.)

It seemed like an easy problem but somehow I can't find an argument for this statement. I guess bijectivity is the hard part of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these functions are bijective and holomorphic, they are also biholomorphic. Define $h(z) = f^{-1}\circ g(z)$. We have $h$ is a biholomorphism of the disk, $h(0) = 0$ and $h'(0) = 1$. By the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) we conclude $h(z)=z$.

Comment: Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz, not Schwartz :)

Comment: Thank you! I corrected it.